# Writing $\cos(x^p)$ as a real part of the exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, exponential-function

If I have 
$$f(x) = \cos (x^p)$$ and I want to write this function as a real part of the exponential function, then which is correct?
$$\cos (x^p) = e^{i(x)^p} \qquad\text{or}\qquad \cos (x^p) = e^{(ix)^p}$$

The first expression feels more natural, but after evaluating some integrals the second expression corresponds to the solutions better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of your proposed solutions is correct, as $\cos(x^p)$ will be real for any real $x^p$, but $\mathrm{e}^{ix^p}$ and $\mathrm{e}^{(ix)^p}$ will both be complex, non-real numbers for many values of $x^p$.  It might be better to think along the following lines:

Recall that for any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) tells us that
$$ \mathrm{e}^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta). $$
Since $\theta$ is a real number and the sine and cosine of a real number is again real, we may conclude from this that for any real $\theta$,
$$ \Re(\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}) = \cos(\theta). $$
With $\theta = x^p$, with $x$ and $p$ chosen so that $x^p$ is real$^{[1]}$, this gives us
$$ \cos(x^p) = \Re\left(\mathrm{e}^{i(x^p)} \right) = \Re\left(\mathrm{e}^{ix^p} \right), $$
which gives $\cos(x^p)$ as the real part of an exponential.

Alternatively, recall if $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then
$$ 2\Re(z) = z + \overline{z}. $$
But then
$$ 2\Re(\mathrm{e}^{i\theta})
= \mathrm{e}^{i\theta} + \overline{\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}}
= \mathrm{e}^{i\theta} + \mathrm{e}^{-i\theta},
$$
which implies that
$$ \Re(\mathrm{e}^{i\theta})
= \frac{1}{2} \left( \mathrm{e}^{i\theta} + \mathrm{e}^{-i\theta} \right). $$
But we saw above that $\cos(\theta) = \Re(\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}$, so we can rewrite this last identity as
$$ \cos(x^p) =  \frac{1}{2} \left( \mathrm{e}^{ix^p} + \mathrm{e}^{-ix^p} \right). $$
Again, we need *a priori* assumptions that $x^p$ is real in order to make the argument presented here hang together.  There are generalizations that allow us to evaluate the cosine of a complex number.  These generalizations follow similar lines, but require a little more care.

[1]:  It might be easiest to assume that $p$ is real, and that $x > 0$.  There are weaker assumptions that will give us $x^p \in \mathbb{R}$, but they are more complicated to state and may not really give us any additional generality.

Answer (score 3):

Since$$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2,$$we have$$\cos(x^p)=\frac{e^{ix^p}+e^{-ix^p}}2.$$

Answer (score 1):

The only correct formula is $cos(\theta )=\Re (e^{i\theta })$.

Note that the formula $ \cos (x^p) = e^{(ix)^p}$ can absolutely not be true, because you may "kill" the $i$ if $p$ is an even integer. You could obtain a value for cosinus that is greater than $1$.

Comment: and things can get far trickier if $p$ is not an integer.